# Spyne. Set Array fixed number items

Tags: spyne

I create the model in spyne with array attribute and I need to fix number items in array.
i.e. my model looks like:

```
class MyModel(ComplexModel):
__namespace__ = 'myns'

string_field = String(**{'min_occurs': 1, 'max_occurs': 1, 'nillable': False})
array_field = Array(Integer(**{'max_occurs': 16, 'min_occurs': 16, 'nillable': False}), 
                 **{'min_occurs': 1, 'max_occurs': 1, 'nillable': False})
```

So, it mean I need to objects with string attribute and array with 16 integer items, but this code direct to xml like:

```
<myns:MyModel>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <myns:string_field>?</myns:string_field>
    <myns:array_field>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <myns:integer>?</myns:integer>
    </myns:array_field>
</myns:MyModel>
```

There is just one integer item in myns:array_field instead 16. What's wrong in my code or is there possible set number of of array's items which I need to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. You can define a constructor and set default values the usual way. i.e.

   ```
   class MyModel(ComplexModel):
       __namespace__ = 'myns'

       string_field = String(min_occurs=1, nillable=False)
       array_field = Array(Integer(max_occurs=16, min_occurs=16, nillable=False),
                    min_occurs=1, max_occurs=1, nillable=False)

       def __init__(self):
           self.array_field = [0] * 16
   ```
2. You can define a default value for the array. Here's a fully working script:

   ```
   from lxml import etree
   from spyne.model.complex import ComplexModel, Array
   from spyne.model.primitive import String, Integer

   class MyModel(ComplexModel):
       __namespace__ = 'myns'

       s = String(min_occurs=1, nillable=False)
       a = Array(Integer(max_occurs=16, min_occurs=16, nillable=False),
            min_occurs=1, max_occurs=1, nillable=False, default=[0]*16)

   from spyne.util.xml import get_object_as_xml

   print etree.tostring(get_object_as_xml(MyModel(s='some_string'), MyModel), pretty_print=True)
   ```